# PCA: mean of marginal distribution of high-dimensional vector

Tags: pca, mean, expected-value, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

Consider the following probabilistic model:

$$p(x) = \mathcal{N}(0, I_d), \ x \in \mathbb{R}^d$$
$$p(y|x) = \mathcal{N}(Wx + \mu, \sigma^2I_D), 
\ y, \mu \in \mathbb{R}^D, W \in \mathbb{R}^{D\times d}$$

Alternatively, one can say that:

$$y = Wx + \mu + \epsilon, \ \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I_D)$$

Marginal distribution p(y) will be again a Gaussian. I saw several times (e.g. in Bishop) as people find mean of the Gaussian:

$$\mathbb{E}(y) = \mathbb{E}(Wx + \mu + \epsilon) = \mu$$

They omit PDF which makes the derivation vague. I tried to make it explicitly:

$$\mathbb{E}(y) = \int (Wx + \mu + \epsilon) p(y) dy =\mu + \int (Wx+\epsilon) p(y) dy = ?$$

How to proceed?

Comment: The expectation is a linear operator, which let's you do that. $W, x$ don't depend on $y$ so they go out of the integral, which then integrates to $1$.

Comment: I agree on linearity. Could you please give the full chain of modifications?